# Why pandas filtering doesn't work on CategoricalDtype while doing a Groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, merge, pandas-groupby

I am trying to run the following piece of code and getting rows still containing the filtered categories.

`merged[(merged['indicator_flag']=='both')].groupby(['indicator_flag','risk_level']).agg({'phone number':'nunique'}).reset_index()`

**Result**

| indicator_flag | risk_level | phone number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| left_only | High | 0 |
| right_only | High | 0 |
| both | High | 1000 |

and so on..

**While my indicator_flag looks like this:**

`merged['indicator_flag'].value_counts().reset_index()`

| index | indicator_flag |
| --- | --- |
| both | 5000 |
| left_only | 20 |
| right_only | 0 |

Is it happening due to the column type being `CategoricalDtype` ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, exactly.

You can avoid it change default parameter `observed=False` in [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

> observed **bool**, default False

> This only applies if any of the groupers are Categoricals. If True: only show observed values for categorical groupers. If False: show all values for categorical groupers.

```
(merged[(merged['indicator_flag']=='both')]
       .groupby(['indicator_flag','risk_level'], observed=True)
       .agg({'phone number':'nunique','match_flag':'sum'})      
       .reset_index())
```